# Tooltip box showing upwards instead of bottom

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```css
.tooltip1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Tooltip text */

.tooltip1 .tooltiptext1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 270px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  /* Fade in tooltip */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}


/* Tooltip arrow */

.tooltip1 .tooltiptext1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.tooltip1:hover .tooltiptext1 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

How do I position it such that it open in bottom. Also as it is opening on top and if I add too much data in span then it goes above page and it cant be scrolled so some part is not visible.Is there a fix to this also in tooltip?

Comment: `tooltip`, `tooltiptext`changes to `tooltip1`, `tooltiptext1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

change this styles,

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  top: 150%; // bottom: 125%; given already
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  bottom: 100%; //top: 100%; given already
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: In this left side of the tool-tip is got hidden also it depends on height of the box. consider what if your div height is 500px your tool tip will start showing from 750px!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  .tooltip1 .tooltiptext1::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent  #555 transparent;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `bottom: 125%;` to `top: 125%;` in `tooltip1 .tooltiptext1`.

```css
.tooltip1 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip1 .tooltiptext1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 270px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    /* Position the tooltip text */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;

    /* Fade in tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

/* Tooltip arrow */
.tooltip1 .tooltiptext1::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip1:hover .tooltiptext1 {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
   <div class="tooltip1">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext1">Tooltip text. 
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore a  assumenda laudantium magnam facere!Eaque perspiciatis eos accusamus inventore  aut!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: ooh give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute as well (here without arrow).

```css
.tooltip {
     position: relative;
}
 .tooltip-bottom:hover::after {
     content: attr(data-tooltip);
     padding: 4px 8px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 110%;
     white-space: nowrap;
     z-index: 1;
     background-color: #000;
     color: #fff;
     border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<span class="tooltip tooltip-bottom" data-tooltip="Tooltip text">Hover me</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

Instead of the following:

```
 /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
```

You can use:

```
/* Position the tooltip text */
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: calc(100% + 5px); /* start from bottom (100%) adding 5px. */
left:0; /* start from the left */
```

And, for the arrow, instead of:

```
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -5px;
 border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
```

Do:

```
 top: -10px; /* position of arrow 5px+5px */
 left: 50%;
 border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent; /* direction of the arrow */
```

Consider the following working example:

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    /* visibility: hidden; */
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    /* Position the tooltip text */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: calc(100% + 5px);
    left:0;

    /* Fade in tooltip */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

/* Tooltip arrow */
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 50%;
            
    /* margin-left: -5px; */
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
   <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the div parent is 120px in this example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Testing tooltips</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 1200px;
        height: 800px;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: black;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0;
        border-radius: 6px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .tooltip-position {
        top: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -60px;
    }
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
    }
    
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="tooltip">Hover over me!
            <span class="tooltiptext tooltip-position">Tooltip text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The arrow positions are:

```
/*Consider 120px parent div as an example*/

//Top
Bottom: 125px;
left: 50%;
margn-left: -60px;

//Bottom
top: 125px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -60px;

//right
top: -5px;
left: 125%

//Left
top: -5px;
bottom: auto;
right: 128%;
```